# Kinesis worker error: Caught exception when initializing LeaseCoordinator

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to execute the sample producer and consumer code on the Kinesis Streams website: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/learning-kinesis-module-one-download.html

I've downloaded the source, and I am using Eclipse to run it. I've included the necessary jar files, so I would think that everything would be setup to run.

When I run the processor code that consumes the records from Kinesis, however, I get this error:

```
Aug 02, 2016 8:35:14 PM com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker initialize SEVERE: Caught exception when initializing LeaseCoordinator
```

Does anyone think they could tell me what is causing this error?

EDIT: Here is the full stack trace from the error on Eclipse:

```
Aug 02, 2016 9:02:27 PM com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker initialize
SEVERE: Caught exception when initializing LeaseCoordinator
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.exceptions.DependencyException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:sts::500238854089:assumed-role/NORD-NONPROD-a0121-Team/AEXM is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:500238854089:table/amazon-kinesis-learning (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: BGME094FRUAEK2KFCPQIAM5U8VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager.createLeaseTableIfNotExists(LeaseManager.java:124)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.initialize(KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.java:172)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.initialize(Worker.java:380)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.run(Worker.java:324)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.samples.stocktrades.processor.StockTradesProcessor.main(StockTradesProcessor.java:96)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:sts::500238854089:assumed-role/NORD-NONPROD-a0121-Team/AEXM is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:500238854089:table/amazon-kinesis-learning (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: BGME094FRUAEK2KFCPQIAM5U8VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1401)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:945)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:723)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:475)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:437)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:386)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2074)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2044)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.createTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:899)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager.createLeaseTableIfNotExists(LeaseManager.java:117)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Your stack trace is telling you exactly what the problem is:

> User: arn:aws:sts::500238854089:assumed-role/NORD-NONPROD-a0121-Team/AEXM is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:500238854089:table/amazon-kinesis-learning

Make sure you've provided credentials to the DynamoDBClient that has CreateTable permissions - LeaseCoordinator attempts to create the leasing table in Dynamo.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to configure logging for Scala Kinesis Enrich by running the jar file like this:

java -jar -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug snowplow-kinesis-enrich-0.5.0 --config enrich.conf --resolver resolver.json

This should print all debug messages from the Kinesis Client Library. (Watch out because the output will become very verbose.) Could you try rerunning with this change to logging? Hopefully that will provide more clues about what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm actually running everything on Eclipse, not in a jar file. If it would be helpful I can post the full stack trace in the original post.